# How can I embed a audio player into a wix website?

Tags: html5-audio, audio-streaming, audio-player

I am trying to add an audio player to my Wix website.  I want the audio player to play different files that can change dynamically by changing the url of the audio file.

There are a number of audio players that I could potentially use: https://freefrontend.com/css-music-players/

I am just not sure how to include them.

- Which code needs to be included in the HTML iframe in Wix?
- Which code needs to be added in the developer console or as a function?
- Which files needs to be stored and can I store them on github?

An example of how to do it will really be appreciated.